# Subtract from a value obtained through variable interpolation

Tags: css, less

I'm having trouble calculating a value when using variable interpolation.

Here's an example on the Less preview site: http://goo.gl/GVHXUs

Below is my code:

```
@breakpoint-sm: 600px;
@breakpoint-md: 800px;

.Mq(@breakpoint; @rules; @maxMin: min) {
    & when (@maxMin = min) {
        @query: ~"(min-width: @{breakpoint-@{breakpoint}})";
        @media screen and @query {@rules();};
    }

    & when not (@maxMin = min) {
        @break: ~"@{breakpoint-@{breakpoint}}" - 1;
        @query: ~"(max-width: @{break})";
        @media screen and @query {@rules();};
    }
}

.test {
    .Mq(sm; {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px
    }; max);

    .Mq(md; {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px
    });
}
```

Result:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px - 1) {
  .test {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .test {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
  }
}
```

So what I'm trying to achieve is that when something other than `min` is passed to the `@maxMin` it should subtract `1` from the breakpoint. I guess I'll be the laughing stock of Stackoverflow now, but hell, I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `~"@{breakpoint-@{breakpoint}}"` is always a string and so the compiler just appends the number to the string instead of performing the math operation.

One way would be to use a temporary variable like shown below (have added only the part that needs modification) and then perform the arithmetic operation.

```css
.Mq(@breakpoint; @rules; @maxMin: min) {
  /* the rest of the mixin */

  & when not (@maxMin = min) {
    @temp: ~"breakpoint-@{breakpoint}";
    @break: (@@temp - 1); /* the braces are mandatory, without which it again appends */
    @query: ~"(max-width: @{break})";
    @media screen and @query {@rules();};
  }
}

/* the selector blocks and mixin calls */
```

---

Below are few things that I found while working on the solution which have left me stumped. I'm trying to find the reason and will update the answer when I do find it out.

- The braces play an important role in the `@break` variable. Without it, the output in media query is still a concatenation. However, if the same variable is used outside the media query (in a normal property-value pair like `prop: @break`, it prints the subtracted value).
- The below code returns concatenated value (800px - 1)

  ```
  @break: ~"@{breakpoint-@{breakpoint}}" - 1;
  prop: @break;
  ```

  whereas the below gives a "Operation on invalid type" compiler error.

  ```
  @break: ~"@{breakpoint-@{breakpoint}}";
  prop: @break - 1;
  ```

  while I can see the reason behind them (first one results in string concatenation whereas second says subtraction can't happen on a string value), I am a bit stumped as to why the behavior is not consistent between the two.

(*You are definitely not a laughing stock. Though I knew the reason for the problem, it took time for me to find a solution*.)